# Filter pandas dataframe rows if any value on a list inside the dataframe is in another list

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a `pandas dataframe` that contains a list in column split_categories:

```
df.head()

      album_id categories split_categories
    0    66562    480.494       [480, 494]
    1   114582        128            [128]
    2     4846          5              [5]
    3     1709          9              [9]
    4    59239    105.104       [105, 104]
```

I would like to select all the rows where the at least one category in a specific list [480, 9, 104].

Expected output:

```
  album_id categories split_categories
0    66562    480.494       [480, 494]
3     1709          9              [9]
4    59239    105.104       [105, 104]
```

I manage to do it using `apply`:

```
def match_categories(row):
    selected_categories =  [480, 9, 104]
    result = [int(i) for i in row['split_categories'] if i in selected_categories]
    return result

df['matched_categories'] = df.apply(match_categories, axis=1)
```

But this code runs on production and this way takes too long (I run it for multiple columns containing lists)

Is there a way to run something like:

```
df[~(df['split_categories'].anyvalue.isin([480, 9, 104]))]
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the maximum size of a list in `df['split_categories']`, e.g. is it always 1 or 2 items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand the inner list, and check if `any` items in the inner lists are contained in `[480, 9, 104]`:

```
l = [480, 9, 104]
df[df.categories.str.split('.', expand=True).isin(map(str,l)).any(axis=1)]

   album_id  categories split_categories
0     66562     480.494        [480,494]
3      1709       9.000              [9]
4     59239     105.104        [105,104]
```

Comment: df.split_categories.str.strip('[]') returns an array of NaN (the value inside split_categories is already a list (not a trsing)
I used df[df.categories.str.split('.', expand=True).isin(map(str,l)).any(axis=1)] instead and it worked. thanks

Comment: Ohh I see, I understood you had to use `split_categories` instead, updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can convert each list to sets, get intersection and convert to bool:

```
L = [480, 9, 104]
mask = np.array([bool(set(map(int, x)) & set(L))  for x in df['split_categories']])
```

Or convert `list column` to `DataFrame`, cast to float and compare with `isin`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['split_categories'].values.tolist(), index=df.index)
mask = df1.astype(float).isin(L).any(axis=1)
```

---

```
df = df[mask]
print (df)
  album_id categories split_categories
0    66562    480.494       [480, 494]
3     1709          9              [9]
4    59239    105.104       [105, 104]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Avoid a series of lists

You can split into multiple numeric series and then use vectorised Boolean operations. Python-level loops using row-wise operations are generally *less* efficient.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'album_id': [66562, 114582, 4846, 1709, 59239],
                   'categories': ['480.494', '128', '5', '9', '105.104']})

split = df['categories'].str.split('.', expand=True).add_prefix('split_').astype(float)
df = df.join(split)

print(df)
#    album_id categories  split_0  split_1
# 0     66562    480.494    480.0    494.0
# 1    114582        128    128.0      NaN
# 2      4846          5      5.0      NaN
# 3      1709          9      9.0      NaN
# 4     59239    105.104    105.0    104.0

L = [480, 9, 104]
res = df[df.filter(regex='^split_').isin(L).any(1)]

print(res)
#    album_id categories  split_0  split_1
# 0     66562    480.494    480.0    494.0
# 3      1709          9      9.0      NaN
# 4     59239    105.104    105.0    104.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

```
my_list = [480, 9, 104]
pat = r'({})'.format('|'.join(str(i) for i in my_list))
#'(480|9|104)' <-- This is how the pat looks like
df.loc[df.split_categories.astype(str).str.extract(pat, expand=False).dropna().index]
```

Or:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in my_list)
df[df.split_categories.astype(str).str.contains(pat,na=False)]

    album_id    categories  split_categories
0   66562       480.494     [480, 494]
3   1709        9.000       [9]
4   59239       105.104     [105, 104]
```

This will work with both `split_categories` and `categories` column.

Comment: str.contains here is better

Comment: @jezrael i had tried, got the warning `UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.` :(

Comment: try `pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)`

Comment: @jezrael that works, thank you. :) will add in edit. :) still learning string formatting. :D

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
print(df[~(df['split_categories'].isin([480, 9, 104])).any()])
```

Output:

```
  album_id categories split_categories
0    66562    480.494       [480, 494]
3     1709          9              [9]
4    59239    105.104       [105, 104]
```